# Are there plans for snap packages to auto-update through Software Centre?

Tags: software-center, snap

Currently, as of the date of this post, you have to run the CLI command snap refresh to update snap packages, manually.

Does Canonical have plans for snap packages to update automatically through the Software Centre like non-snap packages do?

Answer (score 4):

By default `snapd` auto-updates snaps. Check the output of

```
sudo journalctl -u snapd.refresh.service
```

to see how the last updates went.

*Note:* Documentation for this feature is available [here](https://snapcraft.io/docs/keeping-snaps-up-to-date#heading--controlling-updates).

Comment: Thanks dholbach, do you also know if there are any plans for a more user-friendly way to see a history of updates, like an update history in the Software Centre, somewhere?

Comment: That documentation link returns a 404. :(

Answer (score 1):

Since Ubuntu 20.04, Snap updates are also visible in the "updates" section of Ubuntu Software and in the "software updater" program.

In the default configuration, however, snaps update multiple times a day, so it will be rare to actually find a snap update there because they are installed very quickly.